# Dining room vs Kitchen

Tags: word-usage, usage

Normally the place where people eat is the kitchen (or in celebrations they eat in the living room which has a corner with a big table as well). But in huge houses there is a particular room that is aimed for eating only (outside of the kitchen and outside of the living room). My question is if it's possible sometimes to name the kitchen as dining room also (depending on the action. for example while cooking- kitchen and while eating - dining room)

Answer (score 4):

No, the kitchen is never "the dining room". A dining room is always seperate from a kitchen.

That said, often, people have meals in their kitchens either at a table or at a counter. Many modern kitchens have large counters at one end (open-plan-type kitchens) where the counter is like a bar and there are stools. You can sit at the counter and serve a meal there.

Some kitchens also have "breakfast nooks" with a table where people can it and have any meal, not just breakfast.

Comment: A table for eating a meal in a kitchen that is in an area separate from the food preparation (I have one) is sometimes referred to as an "eating area" as well as a breakfast nook. If it's not really separate - for instance, it's used during food preparation - it may just be referred to as "the kitchen table." An old rhyme popular in my family states, "No matter when I serve my guests, they seem to like my kitchen best." :)

Comment: @Fremonttheboybug Your comment is simply not germane to the answer and repeats some of what I said.The point is that a dining room and kitchen are not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. My family has never used the term 'breakfast nook,' but often have used 'eating area' and 'kitchen table' in the sense we're discussing. I'm not trying to quibble, and you've obviously been here longer than I have, and are probably more attuned to the standard type of answer or comment. I voted up your answer. But having said that, everything you added after, "A dining room is always seperate [sic] from a kitchen,' is no more germane, nor is the comment from  Colin Fine below.

Comment: @Fremonttheboybug My answer is the basic idea: kitchens are not dining rooms. You are just going on and on. It doesn't matter if **your family** has a breakfast nook, eating area or kitchen table at which they eat. That is not the point.

Comment: If your answer is the basic idea, then stop there. Don't go on and on. My family are native English speakers. What they call things is informative for non-native speakers.

Comment: Also, please inform John Feltz that he's going on and on.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to be a huge house where people don't eat in the kitchen. Most of the houses I have lived in have not had a kitchen large enough to sit in and eat. Whether a house has a room called the dining room does depend on whether the house has a separate room for that purpose, and that depends on the size of the house. But even there, it doesn't have to be huge to have one.

In any case, I have never heard of a kitchen being called a dining room; except that in some modern flats you find a "kitchen diner", where an open-plan room is primarily a dining room, but with a kitchen at one end or one corner.

Answer (score 0):

A kitchen that is designed so it has room for a dining table is called, not surprisingly, a "dine-in kitchen" or "[eat-in kitchen](http://www.bhg.com/kitchen/eat-in-kitchen/)".